# Branch.io deferred deep linking. How to catch key and value params in Unity c#?

Tags: unity-game-engine, deep-linking, branch.io

I need to set up a deferred deep linking to my app, using Unity Branch SDK. I successfully Integrated Branch to unity project and quick link opens my app. But i can't understand how let link open my specific content. How to read key and value parameters in C# code?

In the article "In-app deep link routing" in documentation  I found - Build custom routing inside the routing callback (https://docs.branch.io/pages/deep-linking/routing/#option-1-build-custom-routing-inside-the-routing-callback) and Auto-routing in Android (https://docs.branch.io/pages/deep-linking/routing/#auto-routing-in-android), but examples are only for android and ios. How can I do this on Unity C# (if this is a deferred deep linking)?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the Unity documentation on reading deep link data [here](https://docs.branch.io/pages/apps/unity/#read-deep-link).

For a deeper dive, you can look at the Unity SDK documentation and code [here](https://github.com/BranchMetrics/unity-branch-deep-linking#branch-metrics-unity-sdk-reference).

Comment: thank you for response. I've already used BranchUnity TestBed. But I looked throw documentation again and found this function -Navigate and Display content (https://docs.branch.io/pages/apps/unity/#navigate-and-display-content), it was very helpful for me.